# Merge rows in datagridview

Tags: c#, merge, datagridview

I am trying to make a billing software and want to merge the rows with same barcode with a press of a button, and if that row contains remark then the row should not merge.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int GROW = dataGridView1.RowCount;
    for(int i=0; i<GROW; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row= dataGridView1.Rows[i];
        string A = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        for(int j = 0; j< GROW; j++)
        {
            if(j == i)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                DataGridViewRow rowb= dataGridView1.Rows[j];
                string B = rowb.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                if (A == B)
                {   
                    string rema = row.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                    string remb = rowb.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                    if(rema == "" && remb == "")
                    {
                        string qa = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                        string qb = rowb.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                        decimal qad = Convert.ToDecimal(qa);
                        decimal qbd = Convert.ToDecimal(qb);
                        decimal tqd = qad + qbd;
                        string ra = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                        string rb = rowb.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                        decimal rad = Convert.ToDecimal(ra);
                        decimal rbd = Convert.ToDecimal(rb);
                        decimal trd = rad + rbd;
                        row.Cells[7].Value = trd;
                        row.Cells[2].Value= tqd;
                        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(j);
                       // i = i - 1;
                       GROW--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your value is in `Cell[2]` and remark in `Cell[8]`, something like this should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        // Check if values are same but remarks are different
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value == dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value != dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[8].Value)
        {
            if (k != 0)
            {
                items.Rows.RemoveAt(j);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = items;
            }
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

*NOTE: I have not tested this code but I hope you get the idea*

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
    private void Merge (DataGridView dataGridView , int barcodeColumnIndex)
   {
    Dictionary<string, DataGridViewRow> barcodeToRow = new 
    Dictionary<string, DataGridViewRow>();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
    {
        string barcodeValue = row.Cells[barcodeColumnIndex].Value.ToString();

        // Check if the row contains a remark. If so, skip it.
        if (row.Cells[8].Value != "")
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (barcodeToRow.ContainsKey(barcodeValue))
        {
            DataGridViewRow firstRow = barcodeToRow[barcodeValue];
            decimal quantity = decimal.Parse(firstRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            decimal newQuantity = decimal.Parse(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            firstRow.Cells[2].Value = (quantity + newQuantity).ToString();

            decimal amount = decimal.Parse(firstRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
            decimal newAmount = decimal.Parse(row.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
            firstRow.Cells[7].Value = (amount + newAmount).ToString();

            row.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            barcodeToRow.Add(barcodeValue, row);
        }
    }

    for (int i = dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (!dataGridView.Rows[i].Visible)
        {
            dataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).